# Reference Custom Field on User Profile

Tags: entities

I'm very close to getting this working right. I created a custom content type with several decimal fields and an entity reference field where you select a user to assign the content to. I am using a computed field to add up the decimal fields and would like to multiply them by a field that I've added to the User profile.

The problem is that I don't know how to reference the field.

This doesn't seem to work:

```
field_get_items($entity_type, $entity, 'field_percentage_split')[0]
```

I'm using Drupal 7. Any ideas?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You should expand the code in your question a little.

First you need to get the assigned uid with something like:

```
$assigned_uid = $node->field_assigned_user[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['target_id'];
```

Then you need to load the user object:

```
$assigned_user = user_load($assigned_uid);
```

Then you have access to the value:

```
$percentage_split = $user->field_percentage_split[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'];
```

To help visualize the $node and $user objects and how to access the information, you can put the [print_r() function into a php-enabled block in your footer](http://k-it.ca/block-show-node-data-structure).

EDIT:

I looked at your code, and you should not try to do everything in a single statement. No wonder you are having problems. Break it out step by step like this:

```
// Get the assigned User ID from the node object

$assigned_uid = $node->field_assigned_user[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['uid'];
// Load the user object for the assigned User.
$assigned_user = user_load($assigned_uid);
// Get the Percentage Split from the user object for the Assigned User (default to 0).
$percentage_split = (isset($assigned_user->field_percentage_split[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'])) ? $assigned_user->field_percentage_split[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] : 0;
// Get the remaining values from the node object, defaulting to 0 if not there.
$other_ins = (isset($node->field_other_ins_[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'])) ? $node->field_other_ins_[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] : 0;
$vb = (isset($node->field_vb[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'])) ? $node->field_vb[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] : 0;
$finder_s_fee = (isset($node->field_finder_s_fee[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'])) ? $node->field_finder_s_fee[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] : 0;
$broker_fee = (isset($node->field_broker_fee[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'])) ? $node->field_broker_fee[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] : 0;
$dlc_franchise_fee_hst = (isset($node->field_dlc_franchise_fee_hst[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'])) ? $node->field_dlc_franchise_fee_hst[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] : 0;

// Do the math.

$value = ($other_ins + $vb + $finder_s_fee + $broker_fee - $dlc_franchise_fee_hst ) * $percentage_split;
```

You also seem to be trying to use D6 data structures (won't work in D7), and it will also not work to try to give a function array keys.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I'm definitely doing something wrong, here is my complete calculation. I have all the isset( because not all the fields will have values, it may be just one or a combination.

http://pastebin.com/u1C3tJPZ

Comment: Also, I'm using decimals and am getting an error about only being able to flip strings or integers.

Comment: The function field_get_items() returns an array, and is not itself an array. "field_get_items($entity_type, $entity, 'field_broker_fee')[0]['value']" is not a valid representation of the field value. get the value of every field the same way I showed you how to get the uid.

Comment: Thank you for the details. Will this fetch the user I'm referencing in my node? I have an entity reference field that references a user. I'd like to fetch the percentage split field from the user that is being referenced.

Comment: $assigned_uid = $node->field_agent[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['target_id'];
$assigned_user = user_load($assigned_uid);
$percentage_split = $user->field_percentage_split[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'];
$entity_field[0]['value'] = print_r($percentage_split); 

That spits out "1.00" regardless of what field I reference from the user profile.

Comment: $user is not $assigned_user, so of course you will not get what you want. I have no idea why you are using print_r in that manner, but if you don't include the second parameter, it will always give you TRUE ("1").

Comment: Thank you so much for walking me through this.

`code $assigned_uid = $node->field_agent[LANGUAGE_NONE][0][uid'];
$assigned_user = user_load($assigned_uid);
$percentage_split = (isset($assigned_user->field_percentage_split[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'])) ? $assigned_user->field_percentage_split[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] : 0;

$entity_field[0]['value'] = $percentage_split; `

I get no errors but the field is blank.

Comment: Solution for anyone who is interested: $node had to be loaded first and 'uid' was replaced with 'target_id':

`code $node = menu_get_object();
$assigned_uid = $node->field_agent[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['target_id'];
$assigned_user = user_load($assigned_uid);
$percentage_split = $assigned_user->field_percentage_split[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'];
$entity_field[0]['value'] = $percentage_split;`

Comment: Glad you worked it out.

Comment: Small issue still: this is looking for the NID on the node_save, which results in an error since the NID doesn't exist yet. When I edit + Save again, everything works. Can I put an if NID doesn't exist, node_save, then run the rest of the code above?