# How to access Machine name fields in PHP?

Tags: 7, webforms, authentication-authorization

If I go to `admin/config/people/accounts/fields` I can see a lot of fields being mapped for LDAP on my server.

For example - for first name there is a machine name "field_fname".

How can I access this on my webform using PHP?

Like I want to display something like this on my webform through PHP:

> "Hello first_name last_name, how are you ?"

Answer (score 1):

Here is a little code snippet that should load the value of field_fname into a variable called $first_name.

```
global $user;
// Load the user object
$user = user_load($user->uid); 

$first_name = $user->field_fname[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reference fields in PHP like this [Reference Custom Field on User Profile](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/64702/computed-field-reference-custom-field-on-user-profile)

I'm not sure about Webforms and PHP but you can retrieve fields with PHP fairly easily.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Ash but I am not understanding from that link. Can you please help me out here?

Comment: Sure, if you look at the answer, he/she shows how to retrieve a field's value using PHP. Then you just print $variable to get it to output. If you don't understand PHP at that level, it'll be challenging. How I learned was by copying and pasting the code, putting in my field's name, and doing some trial and error.